# Отправить запрос из тильды в API

Tags: javascript, tilda

Как в блоке html обратиться к форме, например? Требуется отправить POST-запрос в API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить блок T123 (вставка кода) где написать функцию на JS, что то вроде:

```
<script>
    function sendPost() {
        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
            // code
        }
        httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        httpRequest.open('POST', url)
        httpRequest.send('параметр=' + encodeURIComponent('значение'))
    }
</script>
```

После чего в исходном коде сайта ищем кнопку вызова запроса (предполагается, что мы её уже добавили в zero-блоке к примеру), выписываем её class или id если он есть, находим элемент используя `document.getElementBy...`, и добавляем в код выше после функции событие `addEventListener`. Как найти элемент по ID/классу и как после этого повесить событие клика при помощи `addEventListener` нагуглить крайне просто. Желаю удачи!